# Node heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, heap-memory

I've seen A LOT of questions here on StackOverflow about this, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Currently I'm running

```
node --max-old-space-size=16300 "/path/file.js"
```

But I'm still getting `invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`...

What am i missing? are there other global variable that ca override `--max-old-space-size` ?

Comment: Can you please show what [this](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/os.html#os_os_totalmem) returns? And what's you total memory? In addition show what [this](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/os.html#os_os_totalmem) returns.

Comment: 8-) 16300 is 16GB, no wonder you're getting this error, maybe you should upgrade your machine :P

Comment: @JoseVasquez are 8GB considered on physical memory? I thought that since we use virtual memory, there is a limit on the virtual ram, but that is should be at least double the actual ram... i'm getting this error just pushing 7 billions `0` on a empty array

Comment: I've actually run the same code with C++ and crashes also with it, so probably there is not enough memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are filling an empty array with 7 billions of zeros. When it comes to a Number in NodeJS the same as Javascript is [double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) which means 8 Bytes - by calculating the total size required is 7.000.000.000 Numbers x 8 Bytes / 1024^3 = 52,154 GB which is way more than 16GB the total amount you are specifying by using the console.